# When did error propagation become prominent in physics?

Tags: history, error-analysis

I think is well known that greek scientists and even founding fathers of modern science did not use error propagation in their calculations. Today, instead, is unacceptable to work out any prediction of a physical theory without giving an estimate of how errors on the input parameters propagate into the computed quantity. So my question is:

- when the use of error propagation became prominent? Who has been the pioneer who brought this into physics common practices?

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for [hsm.SE].

Comment: have a look http://delphiforfun.org/programs/Math_Topics/Archimedes_PI.htm